# Splicing a #6 wire to a #8 wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am currently trying to extend an existing electrical line to a garage.  The current line was used for a spa and it has #8 wire and a 50 amp breaker.  I want to switch the 50 AMP breaker out to 60 AMP one.  Currently the #8 wire is spliced about 4' from the circuit breaker and then continues out to a sub-panel.  What size wire do I need to run for a 60 AMP breaker?  Is it possible to splice a #6 or #8 wire into the existing #8 wire for this?  The total run to the garage is about 60'.

Comment: #8 isn't rated for 60 Amps. Is your question about splicing or Ampacity? Please revise to be more clear. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Depending on the wire type you will need #6 or most likely #4 the whole way with a 60 amp breaker.  No #8 allowed on the circuit, so no need for splicing.

Comment: Mechanically, you can usually splice a wire to another one that is a little smaller or larger -- a lot depends on the type of splice. Wire nuts are pretty good if the difference in diameter is not too great.

Comment: @HotLicks  As long as you do not go below minimum gauge of the breaker allowed.

Comment: You could splice it to a jumprope, but both will be illegal for that amperage - even 50A on #8 would require 75C wire and terminations (i.e. not NM-B)

Comment: If this is about EV charging, "you need 60A" is totally wrong. You can get perfectly effective level 2 charging with as little as 20A (as long as it's 240V).  So you can definitely charge without setting any fires.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s